# Getting all attributes and values to a response after an update query in dynamoDB?

Tags: typescript, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table named cart which has attributes such as id, count, description etc. I successfully send the data to the database through a post request but when I try to update the data, it is saved in the database successfully but the response doesn't contain any attributes in the database. As the response I have implemented to receive the same attributes as in the database. I would like to know how to send all the attributes and the values as updated in the database to the JSON response.

```
let response: object;

await dynamoDB.transactWrite({
 TransactItems: [
{
  Update: { // Decrement count of items available to buy only if the count is greater than zero
    ConditionExpression: "#count > 0",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#count": "count" },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
     ":value": 1,
    },
    Key: {
     id: '777-000',
    }
    TableName: "Items",
    UpdateExpression: "SET #count = :count - :value",
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
],
}).promise();
try{
  response = {Items: ..... }
} catch(error) {
  response = {statusCode: 500, body:{message: error.message}};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the new values from the item when using TransactWriteItems operation. You can get new values using the UpdateItem operation by specifying `ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"`.

Comment: Eventhough I specified that, I can't get the attributes and its values to the response.

Comment: @thumalee update your question with the request you tried and the response you received when using the UpdateItem operation. Your question currently shows the TransactWriteItems operation.